# Javascript indexed database how to do a more specific search

Tags: javascript, indexing, indexeddb

I have a javascript indexeddb, each primary index is an two-long incrementing array, from [0,0] to [x,y]:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
...
[1,0]
[1,1]
...
[x,y]
```

My current get request involves the following statement:

```
var transaction = db.transaction("myData", "readonly");
var c = transaction.objectStore("myData");
var a = c.getAll(IDBKeyRange.bound([0,0],[5,5]));
```

However, this gets all data where the first value is between 0 and 5, and does not take into account the second value, sending a return like the following:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
...
[0,y]
[1,0]
...
[5,y]
```

Is there any way to get it to become more precise and take into account the y range? Using a cursor on all of the values is not acceptable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a query with multiple conditions in IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403945/how-to-create-a-query-with-multiple-conditions-in-indexeddb)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/704e9688f99ac12dd336

Answer (score 0):

A key-value store is less (much less?) efficient than a simply array for your data.

If you need to "save" the data between invocations of the web page, then perhaps toss that array into a JSON structure.  That could be a single item in "indexeddb".